# Parallizing loading from a model in file

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a model mesh that I want to load its vertices, indices, in parallel.
The problem is I had to remove return statements if eof is catched for each block, reading vertices, reading faces.
also I'm not sure if that's correct approach. MVP Code is here.

```
    std::ifstream inp(file_name, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
        char buffer[40] = { 0 };
            if (inp.eof()) {
                return false;
            }
            inp.read(buffer, 40);
// making sure it is little endian
            auto ReadUnsignedIntLittleEndian = [&]() {
                unsigned int num = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                    if (inp.eof()) {
                        throw - 1; // throw and exception
                    }
                    inp.read(buffer, 1);
                    unsigned int tmp = (unsigned char)(buffer[0]);
                    tmp <<= (i * 8);
                    num = num | tmp;
                }
                return num;
            };
                auto ReadReal = [&]() {
                inp.read(buffer, sizeof(T));
                T num = *((T*)&(buffer[0]));
                return num;
            };
        // read vertices
            #pragma omp for
            for (int i = 0; i < numVerts; ++i)
            {
                T x = ReadReal();
                //if(inp.eof()) return;
                T y = ReadReal();
               //if(inp.eof()) return;
                T z = ReadReal();
                //if(inp.eof()) return;
                meshPtr->AddVertex(x, y, z);
            }
    
            // read edges
            #pragma omp for
            for (int i = 0; i < numEdges; ++i) {
                int v1 = ReadUnsignedIntLittleEndian();
                int v2 = ReadUnsignedIntLittleEndian();
                meshPtr->AddEdge(v1, v2);
            }
    }
```

Here is how Add Vertex looks like:

```
int Mesh<T>AddVertex(const Vertex<T> vertex)
{
    int vertexIndex = vertices_.size();
    auto v = std::make_shared<Vertex<T> >(vertex);
    v->SetIndex(vertexIndex);
    vertices_.push_back(v);
    return vertexIndex;
}
```

Comment: I believe there is very little performance gain in your approach. Reading from files in parallel typically involve mutexes that will slow things down considerably. Do you have several files? Consider instead to load one file in each thread.

Comment: @SvenNilssonThe mesh size is 250MB, and it takes a lot of time.. is there a better approach ? its just one big file.

Comment: It's almost certainly a very bad idea to try to read a file in parallel as you propose to do.  Think, for a little while, about what happens when 4 threads simultaneously try to read from the same file .... if you are lucky the operating system is going to make sure they all behave politely, each one waiting for the others to finish before taking its turn. It's going to be very slow.  Unless you have special hardware to support parallel i/o ... do you?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark how about reading from file into a std::vector vertices, indices, then paralleize adding them to the datastructure Mesh.

Comment: That could work, a much better idea.

Comment: @SvenNilsson Space versus time complexity :)

Comment: @SvenNilsson Can you elaborate that approach in an answer as pseudo code for openmp part ? as I'm new to it

Comment: The reason adding to mesh takes a lot of time could be that it calls malloc/new for each added vertex. Try to make it allocate larger chunks in advance and it will go much faster.

Comment: @SvenNilsson yes, it does allocate a vertex structure using smart pointer, and it push into a vector container

Comment: @SvenNilsson can you explain more about the larger chunks approach ? the mesh size is unknown at runtime

Comment: The sweet spot for reading files, unless you have the hardware and software for parallel i/o, is to have one thread (or process) read the entire file into memory in one go (if memory is big enough and if the file is only 250MB it probably is).  After that, well then the fun begins.  You may find that having multiple threads simultaneously trying to build one large in-memory object causes so much cache invalidation (etc) it's not worth doing that either.  But that's another question.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark so by any means the serial version is better than the parallel version ? How Game Engines load large files into their datastructures then ?

Comment: It is hard to elaborate because I don't know what your "meshPtr" really is. If it is some kind of vector, you should try to figure out the final size and do a "vector.reserve(finalsize)" before adding anything. Also, your meshPtr may not be thread-safe and would require extra synchronization to use with OMP. The serial version is indeed probably faster.

Comment: @SvenNilsson I have added the missing code, would you take a look ?

Comment: Upload a sample model, and what the format is, and I'm sure someone would be able to read it fast. Perhaps you might even memory map the file and read it that way, or maybe change the format to store the size, then the vertices after. Then the size, and then indices after. That way, you know how much to allocate at once for vertices, and indices, etc. We don't know how you're getting `numVerts` for example. Ideally a sample file is best.

Comment: If your mesh is raw binary, you could read like this fread(vertVector, 3*sizeof(float), numVerts, file); fread(edgeVector, 2*sizeof(unsigned int), numEdges, file); If it is not raw binary, your will get a huge performance gain by converting it to raw binary.

Comment: @Brandon The format is any STL file.

Comment: Your problem is std::make_shared. It is super slow!

Comment: @SvenNilsson The file is indeed in binary, I'm taking about how to use the existing code, to parallize it, especially with the smart pointers

Comment: Smart pointers is something you use for convenience but never performance.

Comment: Before starting parallelizing the code, I would time it and compare the effective throughtput you get (how many MB/s you are able to read) to the sequential read peak performance of the device you are reading the data from (HDD? SSD? Network drive?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load data fast, make your class structure exactly match the file format.

If the file contains repeated binary data:

```
float
float
float
int
```

then your vertex class should be

```
class Vertex {
    float x, y, z;
    int index;
};
```

and reading it will be as easy as this

```
Vertex *data = new Vertex[numVerts];
fread(data, sizeof(Vertex), numVerts, file);
```

Comment: What about parallizing the Vertex data array ? If for example I read from file into vertex structure, then add them into mesh structure.

Comment: Yes, that could be possible, but millions of calls to std::make_shared will introduce a significant overhead because it allocates memory, and therefore may not gain much from the multithreading. Only one thread can allocate memory at a time, so the other threads are forced to wait!

Comment: I would add, as a general comment: "To load data fast, read the file(s) as sequentially as possible". Mutithreading the reads can hurt that... A solution can be to have only the master thread that reads the file (sequentially), and to use OpenMP tasks to fill up the structures.